# What kind of posts does the network profile post count list omit?

Tags: discussion, bug, questions, answers, network-profile

My S.O profile shows 232 answers, while the network profile shows 231 answers.

---

S.O: `stackoverflow.com/users/<id>/<username>?tab=summary`

[image: S.O profile image]

---

Network profile: `http://stackexchange.com/users/<id>/<username>?tab=accounts`

[image: Network profile image]

---

When searching with `is:answer wiki:0` in S.O I get 231 results, and without `wiki:0` 232, meaning I have 1 wiki answer, and 231 non-wiki answers. So I'm guessing only non-wiki posts count towards the total displayed in a network profile.

<strike>So does the network profile post count list omit community wiki posts?</strike>

---

**Update:**

After checking another user's profile, I don't think *only* wiki posts are missing, there could be something else:

S.O.

[image: 2nd S.O profile image]

---

Search: `http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A50079+is%3Aanswer+wiki%3A0&submit=search`

[image: 2nd profile search image]

---

Network Profile

[image: 2nd network profile image]

<sub>(3590 non-wiki answers 3594 total answers 3591 network profile answers).</sub>

---

From the above images it is clear that the count does not depend only on *if a post is wiki or not*.  There is something else going on here.

Why is this mismatch occurring?

Comment: I feel like you answered this yourself. Or am I missing something?

Comment: @usernametbd speculation is not an answer. there are other possibilities...

Comment: @usernametbd i think WE are missing something here, i checked another user's profile, and there things were much different. will update question in a bit, with the new findings.

Comment: FYI i just checked my own profile and noticed the same behavior, so i think your intuition was correct. i would tag this as a bug--not sure why this behavior would be by design

Comment: @jeff i was thinking of tagging this as bug in the beginning, but wasn't very sure then, see the new update, wiki is not the only factor here.